# Deploy SPD Workflow using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am trying  to deploy a SharePoint 2010 reusable workflow through SharePoint Designer 2013. Currently I am doing the below steps:

1. open the site  in SharePoint Designer 2013 [ http://serevr1:123/sites/engineering ]
2. upload the workflow template[ myworkflowtemplate.wsp ] file in the solutions gallery and activate the same [ using import files option in SPD ]
3. right click on the wf and click edit the workflow
4. click on the ribbon in SPD's "publish the workflow globally"
5. associate the WF to "mycustomcontenttype"

can anyone please help how this can be achieved using power shell.
help is appreciated.

Comment: Please try to pay just bit attention to structure of your questions, you will get help quicker if people can read your question also before moderation. Thank you.

Comment: @JussiPalo  thanks for your comment.But i have already mentioned the steps in a detailed manner.

Comment: So you have saved workflow as a wsp and now wants to upload and activate onto the SharePoint site right? Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

If the workflow is saved as a template and we have a wsp file of it, then we can use simple PowerShell script for adding a solution and activate it.

**Add a solution**:

```
Add-SPUserSolution -LiteralPath <LiteralPath> -Site <SiteURL>
```

**Install a solution**:

```
Install-SPUserSolution -Identity <Solution> -Site <SiteURL>
```

**Activate a solution**:

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity <Feature> -Url <URL>
```

You can refer the following useful forum and blog:

[TechNet Forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8767fcc5-2edf-4d52-b7c5-309d98cf371e/sp-2013-use-powershell-to-deploy-activate-and-associate-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow?forum=sharepointadmin)

[TechNet Blog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608051(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: No Problem.. Happy yo help :)

Comment: My workflow have impersonal steps. The workflow will run on behalf of who "publish" the workflow. In the case of "enable-SPFeature" how can we specific the "publisher"?

Comment: @Mark : I have never tried this as `Enable-SPFeature` do not have any such parameter. But try this on the server containing your SharePoint, put your self into local admin group. Open PowerShell ISE in run as another user mode (give your credentials). And run the script.

Comment: @AsadRefai I asked the same question in MS forum and the support told me the only way is connect with SPD and publish the workflow with specific "publisher". It seems Powershell method cannot handle impersonal SDP workflow